# pandas merge does miss values; matching rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare a small pandas.df with a larger one and want to find matching rows. Infact, I know that all rows of the samller Df are part of the larger. They both consist of x, y and z coordinates, so initially I did something like:

```
overlap = pd.merge(largeDF,smallDF,'inner')
```

That seems to work, but gives me only ~50 of the values of the smallerDF. Then I fiddled around for some hours, tried to do is manually and came across this:
So I took some rows from the smaller DF that were missing from the merge and tried to find the values manually.

```
largeDF.loc[largeDF['y']==0.102808]
```

with the output:

```
           x         y         z  ID
14 -0.045073  0.102808  0.593552  14
```

Nice and fine! Thats what I expect.

But then:

```
locationsDF.loc[locationsDF['z']==0.593552]
```

Gives me:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x, y, z, ID]
Index: []
```

But... why? Is that some sort of rounding error that I do not see, because the rows match in the source .txt file. I import them with pd.read_table.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are comparing floating point values for equality. That is unreliable because of the inherently approximate nature of floating-point representation. It is, as you suspect, a roundoff that you can't see that is causing the `if` test to behave differently from the way you expect.

Comment: Mh, but the value come directly from the source document. Its a tab seperated .txt, so there should be the full value, right? That still does not explain, why I loose so many points

Comment: It does. The literal your code is matching is 0.593552. That figure *cannot be accurately represented* in binary floating point because it isn't a sum of powers of 2.

Comment: Instead of `==` try using `math.isclose()`.

Comment: Still, how would I solve the issue with the merging. pandas.merge should take the floating numbers anyhow, right? What is maybe the correct way to save floating numbers with np.savetxt ? I tried default and fmt='%f'

Comment: I say again. *Stop testing for equality.* Use `math.isclose()` instead of `==`.

Comment: math.isclose seems not to work on 'Series' object of the  DF columns and as the documentation states, it seems like a and b have to be single values. Anyhow, I solved the problem by skipping my translation from an numpy array to a pandas Dataframe. Now it seems to save the floating numbers correctly. Thank you for your time!